# How can I modify the settings of the margin item in a list?

Tags: lists, indentation

In the `article` class I have this section of code

```
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength\leftmargini  {2em}
\else
  \setlength\leftmargini  {2.5em}
\fi
\leftmargin  \leftmargini
\setlength\leftmarginii  {2.2em}
\setlength\leftmarginiii {1.87em}
\setlength\leftmarginiv  {1.7em}
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength\leftmarginv  {.5em}
  \setlength\leftmarginvi {.5em}
\else
  \setlength\leftmarginv  {1em}
  \setlength\leftmarginvi {1em}
\fi
\setlength  \labelsep  {.5em}
\setlength  \labelwidth{\leftmargini}
\addtolength\labelwidth{-\labelsep}
\@beginparpenalty -\@lowpenalty
\@endparpenalty   -\@lowpenalty
\@itempenalty     -\@lowpenalty
\renewcommand\theenumi{\@arabic\c@enumi}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\@alph\c@enumii}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{\@roman\c@enumiii}
\renewcommand\theenumiv{\@Alph\c@enumiv}
\newcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.}
\newcommand\labelenumii{(\theenumii)}
\newcommand\labelenumiii{\theenumiii.}
\newcommand\labelenumiv{\theenumiv.}
\renewcommand\p@enumii{\theenumi}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\theenumi(\theenumii)}
\renewcommand\p@enumiv{\p@enumiii\theenumiii}
\newcommand\labelitemi{\textbullet}
\newcommand\labelitemii{\normalfont\bfseries \textendash}
\newcommand\labelitemiii{\textasteriskcentered}
\newcommand\labelitemiv{\textperiodcentered}
```

that set the margins and type of items for the diferent list environments.

How can I modify this to obtain a first margin item equal to `0pt`?

Comment: Why do you want to work at such level. The package `enumitem` offers a very user friendly way to set lists.

Comment: Because I'm creating a new class from `article` class.

Comment: Than have a look at the package `layouts`. It prints all length of the list environment. Based on this information you can manipulate the elements.

Comment: @osjerick Nothing prevents using `enumitem` to define list environments in a class.

Answer (score 7):

To setup a list whether in an own document class, package or in the preamble I recommend the package [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) which is really flexible.

If you avoid such package your must consult the [reference manual source2e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e)

Every environment like `enumerate` or `itemize` based on the environment `list`. The linked reference manual explained the length.

To visualize the length of the current environment you can use the package [`layouts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/layouts) which produced the following output:

[image]

Here the MWE which produced the picture above.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=10,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{layouts}

\begin{document}
\drawdimensionstrue
\listdiagram
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this suit your needs? It sets the left margin to `0pt`, meaning that the bullet or number goes into the margin. Aligning the bullet/number with the margin would be trickier (though perhaps a package can do it for you, I don't know).

```
\setlength\leftmargini{0em}
```

A MWE would then be something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\leftmargini{0em}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}
\item My list 1
\item My list 2
\begin{enumerate}
    \item My nested item
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{itemize}
\item My list 1
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{description}
\item[Label] My list 1
\end{description}

\end{document}
```