Printing out the page size and margins
I am trying to print out the values of the parameters related to the paper dimensions and margins:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[
     width=150mm,
     top=25mm,
     bottom=25mm,
     bindingoffset=6mm, 
     showframe,
     ]{geometry}
\usepackage{layouts}

\begin{document}

\section*{Horizontal}
\begin{itemize}
    \item The paper width: \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\paperwidth}
    \item The text width: \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\textwidth}
    \item The margin parsep:  \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\marginparsep}
    \item The margin parwidth: \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\marginparwidth}
    \item The odd side margin: \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\oddsidemargin} 
    \item The even side margin: \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\evensidemargin} 
\end{itemize}


\section*{Vertical}

\begin{itemize}
    \item The paper height: \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\paperheight}
    \item The text height: \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\textheight}
    \item The head height: \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\headheight}
    \item The head sep: \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\headsep}
    \item The foot skip: \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\footskip}
    \item The top margin: \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\topmargin}
\end{itemize}


\end{document}

But I couldn't find out which parameters give the values of left, right, top, and bottom margins directly. For example, I set up width=150mm by the package geometry and \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\textwidth} prints the value. But I didn't get the same for the top, bottom, left, right margins.
Instead of manually listing the values, how can we print out the values (in mm) and names of each parameter such that it produces something like the following graphic?


Those does not exist as layout values. They are convenience values provided by geometry in order to calculate the values listed in the image via a simple user interface.

The right and bottom margins can only be calculated by subtrackting everything else from  \paperwidth and \paperheight.  Sometimes you can use \evensidemargin, but no guarantees.

Another thing I didn't understand is why my \topmargin is giving a negative value in my MWE.

I haven't tried it myself yet. But checking this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58382/114006), I think the package layouts might help.
